# null value in string attribute (movie name)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple movie-[rating]-user database, with movie attributes as {name,movieID}. 
To convert movieID attribute from string to int, I ran this query (being oblivious that it already was Int) -

```
match (m:Movie) set m.movieID=ToInt(m.movieID)
```

But that created duplicate Movie nodes, without name attribute.

So now when I run the query

```
match (m:Movie{movieID:1}) return m
```

I get two nodes in output-

```
movieID 1

name    Toy Story
movieID 1
```

How do I get rid of the ones without the name attribute? This doesn't work-

```
match (m:Movie) where m.name=null delete m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use IS NULL

```
match (m:Movie) where m.name is null delete m
```

Not sure how the match managed to create duplicate nodes though. Unless they already existed previously with no name?